# Disable tab in .NET

Tags: vb.net, tabs

I cannot disable the tab in VB.NET but Tab container.

any one knows how to disable only tab :/

I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can emulate it with the DrawMode property and the DrawItem and Selecting events.  Easier to just remove tabs that should be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
Dim iTotalTabs = Me.TabControl1.TabCount()
    Dim X As Integer
    For X = 0 To iTotalTabs - 1
        With Me.TabControl1.TabPages(X)
            .Enabled = False
            If .Name = "TabPage2" Or .Name = "TabPage4" Then
                .Enabled = True
            End If
        End With
    Next
```

If this not working for you feel free to ask more.

Regards.